# What folders should I check to see if these MongoDB applications are installed on my server?

Tags: mongodb

I have a CentOS (Linux) server and looked at the /bin directory, but don't find the applications listed below. What folders should I check to see if these applications are installed on my server?

I'm reading a MongoDB book and it states:

After you install or extract MongoDB successfully, you will have the applications show in table 2-1 available in the bin directory (in both Linux and windows).

```
Table 2-1

--bsondump
--mongo
--mongodb
--mongodump
--mongoexport
--mongofiles
--mongoimport
--mongooplog
--mongoperf
--mongorestore
--mongos
--mongosniff
--mongostat
--mongostop
--mongorestore
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find these programs using the Linux `find` command as such:

```
find / -name 'program_name' -print 2> /dev/null
```

Where 'program_name' is for example, `bsondump`.

```
find / -name 'bsondump' -print 2> /dev/null
```

The `2> /dev/null` prevents `find` from printing all the paths it looks at.

Comment: I found them in the /usr/bin directory using your command. Thank you.